# How can I get my input text to move to the left up against the preceding label?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap classes to arrange my page, and it was going fine until my latest row:

```
@* row 7: Copy, Excel, CSV, and PDF buttons  *@
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <button type="button" class="squishedbutton">Copy</button>
        <button type="button" class="squishedbutton">Excel</button>
        <button type="button" class="squishedbutton">CSV</button>
        <button type="button" class="squishedbutton">PDF</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <label style="text-align: right;">Search:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <input type="text" style="margin-right: 2cm;" name="searchinput">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
    </div>
</div>
```

That row is preceded and followed by rows like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <hr />
    </div>
</div>
```

I need the input text to shift to the left, away from the right border, and closer to the "Search" label.

How can I accomplish this?

I also don't know why the row is so tall, making the buttons overly tall - or why the buttons are so tall, making the row tall...

The css used is:

```
.squishedbutton {
  border: none;
  margin-left: 0cm;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

### UPDATE

This is how it looks now:

[image]

...with this html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <button type="button" class="squishedbutton">Copy</button>
        <button type="button" class="squishedbutton">Excel</button>
        <button type="button" class="squishedbutton">CSV</button>
        <button type="button" class="squishedbutton">PDF</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <label style="text-align: right; display: inline-block;">Search:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <input type="text" style="margin-right: 2cm;" name="searchinput">
    </div>
</div>
```

...and this css:

```
.squishedbutton {
  margin-left: 0cm;
  margin-right: -0.1cm;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

IOW, it looks more-or-less "okay" but I would like the input text shifted to the left and/or the label shifted to the right so that they appear a little more "cozy"

Comment: Can you post a Fiddle showing this operating within the Bootstrap framework?  I suspect you can adjust your code to be more form-friendly by relying on `input-group` and `form-group` instead of the structural grid system.

Comment: then <div class="col-md-1">
        <label style="text-align: right; display: inline-block;">Search:</label>
    </div>
would be
<div class="col-md-1 text-right">
        <label style=" display: inline-block;">Search:</label>
    </div>

Comment: @link2pk: That's a little better (moved the label a scosh to the right)

Comment: You won't be able the decrease the spacing further if you want to keep the label and search in different columns because bootstrap column provide a default padding of 15px on both sides of it unless you explicitly override them with your css style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.squishedbutton {
  border: none;
  margin-left: 0cm;
  padding:0 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
  hr{ margin:0;}
 </style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <hr />
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <hr />
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-1">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-7">
    <button type="button" class="squishedbutton">Copy</button>
    <button type="button" class="squishedbutton">Excel</button>
    <button type="button" class="squishedbutton">CSV</button>
    <button type="button" class="squishedbutton">PDF</button>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 ">
    <form class="form-inline">
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputName2">Search</label>
      <input type="text" class="" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="">
     </div>
     
    </form>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-1">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <hr />
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <hr />
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

and if you want label and text to come next to buttons then place them just after buttons.

Comment: This causes the label and input text to display on separate "lines" (stacked vertically instead of side-by-side)

Answer (score 1):

**UPD**. There are three rows in the code below:

1. Original CSS from the answer.
2. Shift `<label>` to right.
3. Place `<label>` and `<input>` in the same column.

Does something look as you need?

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
  }

  /* 1. */
  .shift-to-right {
    padding-right: 0;
    text-align: right;
  }

  /* 2. */
  .make-them-closer {
    padding-top: 13px;
  }
  .make-them-closer label {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 4px;
    padding-top: 3px;
  }
  .make-them-closer div {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .make-them-closer input {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.squishedbutton {
  border: none;
  margin-left: 0cm;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12"><hr /></div>

    <div class="col-md-1">
      <h2>0.</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <button type="button" class="squishedbutton">Copy</button>
      <button type="button" class="squishedbutton">Excel</button>
      <button type="button" class="squishedbutton">CSV</button>
      <button type="button" class="squishedbutton">PDF</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <label style="text-align: right; display: inline-block;">Search:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <input type="text" style="margin-right: 2cm;" name="searchinput">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12"><hr /></div>

    <div class="col-md-1">
      <h2>1.</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <button type="button" class="squishedbutton">Copy</button>
      <button type="button" class="squishedbutton">Excel</button>
      <button type="button" class="squishedbutton">CSV</button>
      <button type="button" class="squishedbutton">PDF</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 shift-to-right">
      <label>Search:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <input type="text" name="searchinput">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12"><hr /></div>

    <div class="col-md-1">
      <h2>2.</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <button type="button" class="squishedbutton">Copy</button>
      <button type="button" class="squishedbutton">Excel</button>
      <button type="button" class="squishedbutton">CSV</button>
      <button type="button" class="squishedbutton">PDF</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 make-them-closer">
      <label>Search:</label>
      <div><input type="text" name="searchinput"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-12"><hr /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Made no difference.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon I've updated my answer. Please check again.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon I've places to my answers together. Now you can see three rows: 0) your original CSS; 1) my first attempt; 2) my second attempt. Please check. Is somethig look as you need?